# EF Code first cascade delete on foreign key one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

We are working in Entity framework Code first

We have a class video

```
class Video{
   List<ImageInfo> Images{
      get; set;
   }
}
```

our image infoclass contains a path to the image and some other info

```
class ImageInfo{
    String path;
    ...
}
```

we would like to have EF remove the imageinfos when removing the video

so we changed the modelbuilder like follows:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Video>()
    .HasMany(v => v.Images)
    .WithRequired()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

we don't want to add a link back to video in our imageinfo class.

is it possible to get cascade delete functionality without a 2 way foreign key?

***EDIT***

the video_id of the imageInfo doesn't get filled in in the database when saving a video.

http://pbrd.co/14X82vb

how can we fix this?

I don't know if its related, but when we add a new video with images at the same time, we get this error:

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.
```

Answer (score 18):

The `WithRequired` introduces the 2 way relationship. So you should do the following.

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Video>()
    .HasMany(v => v.Imgages)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

... and assuming you want the relationship the other way around ...

```
public class Video { }
public class ImageInfo {
    public virtual Video { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder
    .Entity<ImageInfo>()
    .HasRequired(v => v.Video)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

PS: I think the `List<ImageInfo>` should be `virtual`, so here is how I'd define it ...

```
public class Video {
    public Video() { this.Images = new List<ImageInfo>(); }
    public virtual ICollection<ImageInfo> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. We also had a second problem. We assigned a new list to the Images property, causing the database synchronization to fail. So we learned to never assign a new list to a property. (similar with observableCollection and databinding)

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be greatly appreciated then :-). Plus it also helps your own reputation leading to more/better answers.

Comment: we still have the problem of cascading the images on deleting a video: see original question (edited part)